# How is it possible to align two <li> content vertically when one embed an image inside an anchor

Tags: css

I am trying to render an HTML unordered list horizontally with each item having the same length and same height. Both items embed a link. One of the two embed an image. I would like to have item aligned vertically.

I use the `flex` display but am not able to align `li` content vertically.

In the following example `Some text` and the image (here `Logo`), i.e. both orange bordered boxes, should be vertically aligned, which is not the case.

I do not want to change the HTML code (do not want to change the given semantic nor adding element which do not give any new HTML information) but only the CSS
.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <style type='text/css'>
      * {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          border: 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      #navbar {
          background:silver;
      }

      #navbar ul {
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          list-style: none;
      }

      #navbar ul > li {
          flex: 1;
          border: 5px dotted green;
      }
      
      #navbar a {
          border: 5px dotted orange;
      }
      #navbar img {
          height: 80px;
          vertical-align:middle;
      }   
    </style>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <body>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Some text</a></li>
        <li><a id="logo" href="#"><img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="Some Logo" /></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `align-items: center;` to the container that has `display: flex;` as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <style type='text/css'>
      * {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          border: 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      #navbar {
          background:silver;
      }

      #navbar ul {
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          list-style: none;
          align-items: center;
      }

      #navbar ul > li {
          flex: 1;
          border: 5px dotted green;
      }
      
      #navbar a {
          border: 5px dotted orange;
      }
      #navbar img {
          height: 80px;
          vertical-align:middle;
      }   
    </style>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <body>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Some text</a></li>
        <li><a id="logo" href="#"><img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="Some Logo" /></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. I had tested this one but I was using `middle` as a value instead of `center`. I am just and old stupid donkey unable to work correctly after midnight :-(

Answer (score 0):

change your navbar css like this

```
#navbar ul {
display: flex;
flex-direction:column;
align-items:center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: It cannot render the way I want(every item on a line) if I use `flex-direction: column`, did it?